# Correlated regressors in linear regression

Tags: regression, outliers, multicollinearity, linear

I have a sample of 412 young subjects, measured twice in an interval between 20 days and 3 years.
I am interested in how two external factor (lets say sunlight and ice-cream) relates to growth. Subjects were exposed to sunlight and ice-cream somewhat randomly, and I have calculated the cumulative exposure (CE) as the sum of sunny days over the time between the measures (CE_sun), and the sum of ice-cream over the test period (CE_ice-cream)
So, for example, subject A was tested on June 1 and June 30,  and those 30 days were all sunny days with lots of ice-cream,  so Subject A has a CE_sun of 30 (June 1 sun, June 2 sun, ...) and a CE_ice-cream of 30 (ice cream every day). Subject B was tested on November 1 and November 30, but since november was gloomy, she only had 5 days of CE, and 0 CE_ice-cream.

So in my linear regression, I have a factor for subject age, a factor for time between measures, and factors for CE_sun and CE_ice_cream. I want to test if CE_sun and CE_ice-cream effects growth.
The problem is that that time between tests is highly correlated to CE_sun (r=0.97) and to CE_ice-cream (r=0.898). CE_sun also correlates with CE_ice-cream (r=0.78). So in the linear regression, I am not sure the CE_sun and CE_ice-cream are estimated well.
To convince myself, an idea was to define the 100 subjects where "time between tests" and CE_sun and CE_ice-cream are **least** correlated, and run the linear regression in this subset. In this subset, the correlation between time and CE_sun is R = -0.10, time and CE_ice-cream is r=0.70, and between CE_sun and CE_ice-cream r= -0.77.

Is this approach incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes. You're basically cherry-picking data to find an effect.

If you have significantly correlated predictors, you should consider removing some of them.

Comment: You may not want to remove them straight away, as you could lose some information held there.  You may consider grouping the variables and making them orthogonal via principal components.

Comment: This, of course, depends on whether or not you can actually interpret the principal components.

Answer (score 0):

Well seems really obvious to me why time between has such correlation with Sun and Ice-Cream. A quick way to tackle with this is to find the mean of each day in Sun and Ice-Cream $\frac{CESun}{TimeBetween}$ and $\frac{CE Ice-Cream}{TimeBetween}$ for each subject.
Using the two new variables, you should not have the same problem and be able to interpret the regression much easier.